# Handling selectedValues from Multiple drop-downs using ng-repeat and ng-options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```html
<li ng-repeat="questionAndAnswers in questionnaire">
  <select ng-model="selectedAnswer" ng-options="answer as answer.displayText for answer in questionAndAnswers.answers track by answer.value" ng-change="validateAnswers()">
  </select>
</li>
```

```js
"questionAndAnswer": [{
  "question": "Is your camera fully functional?",
  "answers": [{
    "displayText": "Yes, everything works",
    "value": "Success"
  }, {
    "displayText": "Some of the buttons are broken",
    "value": "Failure"
  }]
}, {
  "question": "Does your camera has any obvious damage?",
  "answers": [{
    "displayText": "No it's perfect",
    "value": "Success"
  }, {
    "displayText": "Yes, there is heavy damage",
    "value": "Failure"
  }]
}]
```

I am creating multiple drop-downs based on the size of questionaire (json sample given) using ng-options and ng-repeat. Could someone please suggest the best angular way to get the answers in validateAnswers() javascript where I may validate if the user has selected "Success" answer. If all the answers are Success, I would need to display a success message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use $index to store the answers in an array and validate the array in the validateAnswer function.

In your html : minor tweek :

```
<li ng-repeat="questionAndAnswers in questionnaire track by $index">
   {{questionAndAnswers.question}}<br>
   <select ng-model="selectedAnswers[$index]" ng-options="answer.value as answer.displayText for answer in questionAndAnswers.answers" ng-change="validateAnswers()">
   </select>
 </li>
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.questionnaire = [{
  "question": "Is your camera fully functional?",
  "answers": [{
    "displayText": "Yes, everything works",
    "value": "Success"
  }, {
    "displayText": "Some of the buttons are broken",
    "value": "Failure"
  }]
}, {
  "question": "Does your camera has any obvious damage?",
  "answers": [
  {
    "displayText": "No it's perfect",
    "value": "Success"
  }, 
  {
    "displayText": "Yes, there is heavy damage",
    "value": "Failure"
  }]
}];

$scope.selectedAnswers = [];  

$scope.validateAnswers = function() {
  console.log($scope.selectedAnswers);
  var allSuccess = true;
  for (i = 0; i < $scope.questionnaire.length; i++) { 
    allSuccess = allSuccess && ($scope.selectedAnswers[i] === 'Success');
  }
  if (allSuccess) {
    $scope.result = 'Congratz! All answers correct!';
  } else {
    $scope.result = '';
  }
}
```

Here is a working example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pbp0hURttnSyNHr1mCK1?p=preview)

Personally I would use booleans as value for your answers instead of strings 'Success' and 'Failure' if you only have these two values.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks, it exactly solved my problem. To add, in my case $scope.questionnaire comes dynamically, so instead of initializing selectedAnswers as two length array, I initialized it as empty array [] and in the loop, I checked it against $scope.questionnaire.length.

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer to apply for any length of questionnaire.